# SpEL formatted Query Spring Data JPA w/ Spring Security

Tags: spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Data JPA Entity

```
@Entity    
public class User  {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Long id;
```

Which I want to include a property `mutualFriends` which is the result of a query against the querying user `principle` (in Spring Security), using `SpEL` and the [EvaluationContext extension model](https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions)?:

Following the SpEL examples I came up with something like this:

```
@Formula("select count(friendship) from Friendship friendship where " +
        "friendship.owner.id = id " +
        "and friendship.friend in " +
        "(SELECT f.friend FROM Friendship f where f.owner.id = " +
        "?#{principle != null ? principal.id : id}) ")
    private Integer mutualFriends;
```

The same entity (`User`) is used when authentication user's so I need to have some logic to determine if the `principle` is available yet or I get an error:

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No value specified for
>   parameter 2.

```
?#{principle != null ? principal.id : id}
```

Is this formatted correctly?

Here is the relevant part of the hibernate query that is executed when I get the exception:

```
select user0_.id as id1_19_, user0_.created_by as created_2_19_, user0_.created_date as created_3_19_, user0_.last_modified_by as last_mod4_19_, user0_.last_modified_date as last_mod5_19_, user0_.activated as activate6_19_, user0_.activation_key as activati7_19_, user0_.avatar_url as avatar_u8_19_, user0_.banner_url as banner_u9_19_, user0_.description as descrip10_19_, user0_.email as email11_19_, user0_.first_name as first_n12_19_, user0_.lang_key as lang_ke13_19_, user0_.last_name as last_na14_19_, user0_.login as login15_19_, user0_.online as online16_19_, user0_.password_hash as passwor17_19_, user0_.reset_date as reset_d18_19_, user0_.reset_key as reset_k19_19_, user0_.test_data as test_da20_19_,
```

select count(user0_.friendship) 
    from Friendship friendship 
    where friendship.friend in (
        SELECT f.friend 
        FROM Friendship f 
        where f.owner.id = COALESCE(?#{principle != null ? principal.id : user0_.null},user0_.id)) 
        and friendship.owner.id = user0_.id as formula2_ 
        from user user0_ where user0_.login=?

SpEL/JPA correctly implements replaces `id` with `user0_.id`, but something is still missing? *Also, it does not appear that `select count(user0_.friendship) from Friendship friendship where friendship.friend in (SELECT f.friend FROM Friendship f where f.owner.id = COALESCE(?#{principle != null ? principal.id : user0_.null},user0_.id)) and friendship.owner.id = user0_.id as formula2_` portion of the query has been correctly parsed?*

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, completely missed the obvious:

`@Formula` is a Hibernate thing. It knows nothing about SpEL and wound evaluate such expressions.

What you can do, and what the example you linked to does is: create a method in your repository, add a `@Query` annotation and use SpEL in there.

Comment: In lots of places throughout the application the `User` entity is linked to other entities, wouldn't I have to re-run the `@Query` method to pull the ? OR can I add `@Query` directly to the `@Entity` annotated class?

Comment: You can put Named Queries on the entity (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.named-queries) but again this is a JPA feature and won't support SpEL.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem might be that `id` is not known in the SpEL context. Replacing the SpEL expression with

```
COALESCE(?#{principle != null ? principal.id : null},id)
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Gave it a try, same result