# Spring Data JPA Subquery Objects matching Spring Security User

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-security, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to extract a count of "mutual friends" when I fetch a `User` annotated with `@Entity`, preferably *without* having to iterate over all paginated results and query for the appropriate values.

This means that *for any given user the result maybe different depending on whom is reading the database*. Basically the following query:

```
select count(friendship) from Friendship friendship where 
        friendship.owner.id = user_id and friendship.friend in 
        (SELECT f.friend FROM Friendship f where f.owner.id = current_user_id)
```

Where **user_id** is the user being selected and **current_user_id** is logged in user.

The user whom should be compared is the `Principle` as defined by Spring Security, and SpEL format: `?#{principle}`

I [found out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46780333/spel-formatted-query-spring-data-jpa-w-spring-security/46784863?noredirect=1#comment80518766_46784863) that `@Formula` is *hibernate* and does not apply [SpEL](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions), so I would have to use `@Query`.

I can not think of an efficient way to do this, save possibly defining a new database table (I'm using Postgresql) and updating it when friendships are updated.

Here is a basic look at what my friendship entity is like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "friendship")
public class Friendship {

@Id
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="owner_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
private User owner;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="friend_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
private User friend;
```

Each new "friendship" gets two of these records created so I can easily query any user's friend-list.